# unable to serve Django media files on the server?

Tags: python, django, media

I am using a Django version - 2.0.6.
and running the server on google compute engine VM instance.

My apache files are not configured to server the production base and local settings differently.
Currently the settings are running from base.py and local.py.

I have configured my media and static files like this:

my settings module(both base.py and local.py):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), "static-root")



MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), "media-root")
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
....
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I try to upload any media file it does not get saved in the "MEDIA_ROOT" location rather it get saved in "MEDIA_DIR".

How to serve media_root and media_dir in production?(/var/www/venv)

Static files are functional.

**Hierarchy**:

```
/var/www/ ----->media-root
               >static-root
               >venv--->src--->manage.py
                              >media
                              >static
                              >other apps & settings
```

Comment: replace with this MEDIA_URL = '/' in your django settings.

Comment: Thank you very much @TarjeetSingh it worked...Can you explain me the reason...As I am new to django it will help me in my learning process...

Comment: it means its  a absolute path of media directory , if you add anything after '/' it finds that path inside the media(root)  directory.

Comment: Thank you very much...That helps@TarjeetSingh